# Error gateway response

Tags: javascript, gateway

I have a question about the process of the payment using a gateway emerchant. I have to provide all the variables to the gateway and get the answer if the charge was made. I can make the charge if all the data is correct, but i don't know how to receive the answer from the gateway, the manual give me a clue, the answer will provide in the variable "urlBack". Do you know how to get data from this gateway?

First I process all date in javascript then I send the information using the following code, but the answer I will receive in another page (https://acmax.mx/popup_2). All works very well but I have problems with the answer from the gateway.

Thank so much

```
    <form name="myPayTC" id="myPayTC" method="post" action="https://www.procom.prosa.com.mx/eMerchant/7727222_acmaxdemexico.jsp" onload='javascript:MyFrmOnLoad();'>

    <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value='total'>
    <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="484">
    <input type="hidden" id="address" name="address" value="ACMAX">
    <input type="hidden" id="order_id" name="order_id" value='order_id'>
    <input type="hidden" id="merchant" name="merchant" value="7727222">
    <input type="hidden" id="store" name="store" value="1234">
    <input type="hidden" id="term" name="term" value="001">
    <input type="hidden" id="digest" name="digest" value='valDigest'>
    <input type="hidden" id="return_target" name="return_target" value="N/A">
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="urlBack" name="urlBack" value="https://acmax.mx/index.php?controller=ComercioResp">-->
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="urlBack" name="urlBack" value="https://acmax.mx/es/checkout/confirm">-->
    <input type="hidden" id="urlBack" name="urlBack" value="https://acmax.mx/popup_2">
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="urlBack" name="urlBack" value="http://acmax.mx/es/checkout/paymentmethod">-->

    <p><img src="https://acmax.mx/themes/theme674/img//bankwire.jpg" alt="Pago por tarjeta de cr&eacute;dito/d&eacute;bito" width="86" height="54" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="pButton" value="Pago con Tarjeta de Cr&eacute;dito/D&eacute;bito" class="exclusive" style="font-size:14px; height:28px;"></p>

    </form>
```

The code that has the server is the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <HTML version="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Verificacion de Compra</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <form id="formars" name="formars" action="https://acmax.mx/popup_2" method="post">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Response" value="denied">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Total" value="102">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_OrderID" value="625">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Merchant" value="7727222">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Store" value="1234">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Term" value="001">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_RefNum" value="initialrefnum">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Auth" value="000000">
    <input type="Hidden" name="EM_Digest" value="initialdigest">

    <input type="Hidden" name="cc_number" value="0565">
    <input type="Hidden" name="total" value="102">
    <input type="Hidden" name="order_id" value="625">
    <input type="Hidden" name="merchant" value="7727222">
    <input type="Hidden" name="tx_id" value="322307f91ef2b5318e5d720f49fb30dace2ca474">


            <input name="pButton" value="Pago con Tarjeta de CrÃ©dito/DÃ©bito" type="Hidden" />

            <input name="address" value="ACMAX" type="Hidden" />

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var formars = document.getElementById('formars');
    formars.submit();

    </script>
    </BODY>

    </HTML>
```

I can't change this code, so I need to get the data from the form "formars"

Comment: They will most likely send a `POST` request back to the url you supply as the `urlBack` parameter, Whomever the gateway is, they should have instructions about the data fields they would post back. You can then parse the data with whatever language you have available, .NET, PHP etc.

Comment: Thank you  "mikeyq6" I have the parameter that the gateway return, but I don't know how to get this data,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for example, if you have set the `urlBack` parameter to some php page, let's call it `returnCall.php`.

Now, if the payment gateway is sending back the following 'post' data:

`name1=cat&name2=dog&name3=echidna`

Then in your php page, you can read that data as follows:

```
<?php
   $value1 = $_POST["name1"];
   $value2 = $_POST["name2"];
   $value3 = $_POST["name3"];
?>

<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Value1 = <?=$value1?></li>
        <li>Value2 = <?=$value2?></li>
        <li>Value3 = <?=$value3?></li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

Then the output on the page would translate to:

```
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Value1 = cat</li>
        <li>Value2 = dog</li>
        <li>Value3 = echidna</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

You could similarly have an aspx page that could do the same thing.

```
string Value1;
string Value2;
string Value3;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Value1 = Request.Form["name1"];
    Value2 = Request.Form["name2"];
    Value3 = Request.Form["name3"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mikeyq6, I have the following code, that is the same that you suggested, but it code only works in a server with php, in my case i don't have php, only asp.net, javascript jquery and html.
"EM_Response= <?php echo $_POST["EM_Response"];?> <br>
EM_Total= <?php echo $_POST["EM_Total"];?> <br>
EM_OrderID= <?php echo $_POST["EM_OrderID"];?><br>

Comment: The payment gateway has address https://www.procom.prosa.com.mx/eMerchant/7727222_acmaxdemexico.jsp So I think I can get the data using javascript, it is possible?

Comment: You could use ajax calls to do it, but you will run into difficulty with the cross domain restriction. See [here for more information on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain).

Comment: See my edit, I added an example in `.NET`. Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you mikeyq6, let me to try and I wil replay.

Comment: I have try the code but stil I can't get the data, could you help me with some code using html or javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem actually is. You have the second page which contains all of the fields from the payment gateway response, right? What is it that you can't do?

Comment: Thank you so much mikeyq6, the code that you provide is working, my problem was the page were I was doing the test. Now is working, than you.